# Installed PostGIS extension not listed for database?

Tags: postgis, installation

I have a PostgreSQL database with the PostGIS extension enabled.

I know that this extension is enabled, since I am using PostGIS functions, and I can actually see the PostGIS functions.

However, PostGIS is not listed in the installed extensions section, and thus I can't alter it nor uninstall it.

If I try

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

it tells me that PostGIS is already installed, and that I should uninstall it first. However

```
DROP EXTENSION postgis CASCADE;
```

tells me that no PostGIS extension is installed.

What can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of postgre you use ?

Comment: What about the result of:                            SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();

Comment: It works, apparently I am using PostGIS 2.1.2 with PostgreSQL 9.3.5

Comment: Is the schema always the same? I ask this because the installation of postGIS extension is at schema level.

Comment: Actually the reason I need the PostGIS extension to show up as an installed extension is because I want to change it's schema. It currently resides completely in "public", I would like to move it to its own schema, but I cant, since "ALTER EXTENSION ..." doesn't work. I could install PostGIS in a new schema and delete everything by "hand" in "public", but then my geometry columns in my tables are lost.

Comment: So finally, the goal is to migrate spatial data that resides in the "public" schema in another specific schema. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MickyInTheSky, check out how to [Change schema of multiple PostgreSQL tables in one operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218768/change-schema-of-multiple-postgresql-tables-in-one-operation) for migrating your data to another schema.

Answer (score 6):

I got it, the problem was, that I had an old Postgres/PostGIS install, from a time where EXTENSIONS where not supported (I didn't create the database).

That's why it didn't show up in the extensions, after following the ["HARD UPGRADE" guide](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#upgrading) it worked (just remember to use extensions for the *newdb*)!